# Как сделать секундомер в ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

Всем привет. Хочу сделать секундомер на Asp.Net MVC. Что лучше использовать SignalR или что-то другое? Приложение очень простое, на экране кнопка старт, после нажатия начинает тикать секундомер от нуля и выше. После нажатия кнопки стоп, таймер останавливаетя.

Answer (score 0):

Не то что бы я был вебером или знал ASP.NET но подозреваю что здесь нужен конкретно JS скрипт который и будет делать нужную работу. И по самому таймеру и по обновлению текста в нужном месте.
Я не знаю какие JS библиотеки ты конектишь к своему проэкту, но если конектишь тот же JQuery там должно быть что-то достаточно удобное для твоей задачи.

Вот здесь можно найти пример для jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604450/how-to-create-a-jquery-clock-timer

Если ты конектишь другие js библиотеки - используй их и гугли в том направлении. Таймер стартуй или по нажатию кнопки или по финишу документ лоад -- как тебе удобнее.